# Checkbox value to change from 0 to 1 when custom span is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to use the custom checkbox styling in a form I am building [here](http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do)

When I click the label of the checkbox, the value of the checkbox changes from 0 to 1 or vice-versa. However, if I click the span box itself that holds the custom image style, the value does not change. Below is a sample of the HTML and the jQUery code I am using to change it. I want the value to change when the span is clicked too.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12  tick1">
 <span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0px -48px;"></span>
 <input type="checkbox" name="custom9" id="custom9" class="styled">
  <label for="custom9">Have you received your entire order from Plush?
  <span class="mandatory tick1Mandatory"> * </span> </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#custom9').on('change', function () {
  this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
}).change();
```

Comment: fyi, the value of a checkbox does not matter if it's not checked as it's never submitted.

Comment: The value of the checkbox gets passed on during sumbit and hence need it to change to 1 when checked

Comment: No, an unchecked checkbox is not transmitted when submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works well for me in "chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m", "firefox Version 22.0". but if don't work in other browsers, you can test below code:

***[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cvWDH/1/)***

```
$('div.ticks div.col-xs-12 input,div.ticks div.col-xs-12 input label').on('click',function () {
 // this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;    
 var checkBox = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
checkBox.value = checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0;    
});
```

Comment: @Himu did u see jsfiddle link? you can try your code there. may be the problem is not because of code... dose your browser allow javascript to run?

Comment: Hi found the problem. It was a problem with my js file. Thanks for your help. Your code actually works with the description given above. I had issues with my javascript.